# ViewModel in fragment clears values on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

Guess I'm missing something obvious here but... I'm storing data in `uiModel` in the **DiaryViewModel** class, and since I use architecture components I'm expecting the data to be retained through screen rotation - but it doesn't. I'm blind to why.

Here's a stripped down fragment

```
class DiaryFragment: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: DiaryViewModel

    override onCreateView(...) {
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DiaryViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.getModel().observe(this, Observer<DiaryUIModel> { uiModel ->
            render(uiModel)
        })
    }
}
```

And the corresponding view model.

```
class DiaryViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var uiModel: MutableLiveData<DiaryUIModel>? = null

    fun getModel(): LiveData<DiaryUIModel> {
        if (uiModel == null) {
            uiModel = MutableLiveData<DiaryUIModel>()
            uiModel?.value = DiaryUIModel()
        }

        return uiModel as MutableLiveData<DiaryUIModel>
    }
}
```

Can any one see what's missing in this simple example? Right now, `uiModel` is set to `null` when rotating the screen.

Comment: What version of support libraries are you using? v26.1.0 included support for `Lifecycles` (though not certain that would be cause of issue you're seeing)

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly 27.0.2. I've also read that this might be the issue, but that it was fixed in version 26. Guess I'm facing something different.

Comment: This might be related to lifecycle of the fragment....not necessarily a solution in itself but what I typically do is pass `activity` in to `ViewModelProviders.of()` but you'd also need to check that that makes sense for your particular use case (example of doing that is shown in https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing)

Comment: Indeed. I tried that but it didn't work :/ Made no difference.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue was with how the activity was handling the fragment creation. **MainActivity** was always creating a new fragment per rotation, as in

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(overlay.id, DiaryFragment.newInstance())
        .commit()
}
```

But of course, it works much better when checking if we have a saved instance, as in

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(overlay.id, DiaryFragment.newInstance())
            .commit()
    }
}
```